# rspec to test whether ruby method returns an array

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a method which returns an array. I need to test it using rspec. Is there any method with which we can test like:

```
def get_ids
  ####returns array of ids
end

subject.get_ids.should be_array
```

or

```
result = subject.get_ids
result.should be an_instance_of(Array)
```

Comment: `result.class.should eq Array`

Answer (score 25):

Well, depends on what exactly you're looking for.

To check if the returned value is an array ([be_an_instance_of](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations#typesclasses)):

```
expect(subject.get_ids).to be_an_instance_of(Array)
```

or to check if the returned value matches the content of expected array ([match_array](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations#collection-membership)):

```
expect(subject.get_ids).to match_array(expected_array)
```

**Update**:

As mentioned in Patrick's comment, to check equivalence match of array use `eq`:

```
expect(subject.get_ids).to eq(expected_array)
```

For identity match of array use `equal`:

```
expect(subject.get_ids).to equal(expected_array)
```

Comment: `eq` will also work if you know the contents of the array. I think in this case it is best to do an exact match.

Comment: @p11y : Actually `eq` will do an exact match while `match_array` will check if contents of the source array matches exactly with the target array, i.e., `expect([1, 2, 3]).to match_array([3, 2, 1])` will work while `expect([1, 2, 3]).to eq([3, 2, 1])` won't. Or I misunderstood your point? Here, you may not know the order of ids you get from the method, so you might not want to do an exact array match, instead better to do an exact content match.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that I tend to prefer the most restrictive assertion possible. I generally start out with `eq` and only when I notice that I don't care about order, I switch to `match_array`. It is easy to form a habit using `match_array` and then miss cases where the order is important. Same principle applies to other kinds of assertions, for example I prefer `eq('Hello, Zaphod!')` above `match(/Zaphod/)`. It's easier to understand and at the same time more specific. Of course there are exceptions to this, above all when you don't want your tests to break when other units change.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Completely agree with your point on forming this as a habit and then carrying it on in future. Sometimes an exact match is necessary to see if your code is producing the desired output. For example: You might not want to use `match_array` if you're testing a sorting/filtering functionality.

Comment: What about `expect(subject.get_ids).to respond_to(:each)`?

Comment: @GiovanniBenussi : You wouldn't know if it is a Hash or some other object responding to `each` due to duck typing.

Comment: Thanks true @Surya. I was trying to give a solution that doesn't break if we change the instance class (e.g: a class that inherits from Array), but I guess that for this case use it is ok :-)